# getting node.js app to work on port 3001

Tags: apache, node.js

ok, this one is confusing me greatly!

If I add this to my apache conf:

```
ProxyRequests off

<Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

<Location /node>
    ProxyPass http://localhost:3001/
    ProxyPassReverse http://localhost:3001/
</Location>
```

now, when I go to  .../node, i see the following page:

"Welcome to socket.io."

But what I want to happen, is to see that page by typing in website:3001, but this just doesn't work. Why might this be?

Addiitional:

The server has a private IP, to which the router forwards IP traffic on ports 3000 and 3001. I can load the page using curl or wget using the private IP, but not the public IP. Any ideas why this might be?

Comment: there is no point in using node via apache! it has too much overhead. node by its own is a http and tcp server, no need for apache.

Comment: So what is stopping mywebsite:3001 from taking me to the page that displays: "Welcome to socket.io." ?

Comment: @user2029574 Make sure your Node app isn't only listening for requests to `localhost` -- `.listen(3001, '127.0.0.1')`. It needs to be listening to the IP address of `mywebsite` as well -- `.listen(3001, 'mywebsite')`. Or, just have listen to any IPv4 addresses -- `.listen(3001)`. Also make sure your firewall is allowing inbound communication on port `3001`.

Comment: The node app is not listening on one ip, just .listen(3001). I am assuming the port is open because if I have the apache proxy as above, then I am routed to the page. But mywebsite:3001 does nothing!

Comment: possible duplicate of [selective proxy port forwarding on Apache httpd](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18561049/selective-proxy-port-forwarding-on-apache-httpd)